# PHP Warning: A non-numeric value encountered – header

Tags: php

I am getting this warning from my hosts's logfile.

```
$header_top_padding_height   = ( ( $cg_logo_height ) + ( $cg_padding_above_logo ) );
$header_total_height        = ( ( $cg_logo_height ) + ( $cg_padding_above_logo ) + ( $cg_padding_below_logo ) );
```

[image: Code picture]

Would be absolutely thankful if anyone could give me a tiny hint!
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: One of the values is a string, not an integer. `var_dump` them and see what you actually have.

Comment: the image of the code is completely unuseful, please remove it and post only the code as text

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what values your variables are getting but you can always cast them to be an integer if you're unsure.

```
$header_top_padding_height = ( (int)( $cg_logo_height ) + (int)( $cg_padding_above_logo ) );
```